# Counting only distinct rows with Rows Offset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have the following table

```
ID    |     Name
1     |     John
2     |     Kevin
2     |     Sam
2     |     Fred
3     |     Frank
3     |     Jessica
4     |     Emily
5     |     Lauren
6     |     James
```

How would I configure the offset so that I am only counting distinct ID values?
so if it was

```
OFFSET @Start ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

My result would look something like

```
1  John
2  Kevin
2  Sam
2  Fred
3  Frank
3  Jessica
```

Now it is selecting 3 distinct ID values. So essentially, is there a way to page by distinct values when using the row offset?

Comment: offset-fetch in SQL Server doesn't support WITH TIES. You can use analytic RANK instead of OFFSET

Comment: use dense_rank partition by id

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to generate row numbers for each id group, and then use your offset function on the result.

That inner query will select everything from your table and:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [NAME]) as RowNum
```

and then only select rows with a RowNum = 1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with an `offset`, I don't think.  Instead, you can enumerate the distinct values and choose them three at a time.

```
select t.id, t.name
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where (seqnum - 1) / n = @start
order by id;
```

Here you would increment `@start` by 1 each time.

Note that if you wanted to get 3 rows and then keep ties, you would use:

```
select top 3 with ties t.id, t.name
from table t
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to accomplish this.  I would try several scenarios to see what fits best with your situation for performance.

```
DECLARE @start int = 0
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY id ASC
    OFFSET @Start ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
)
```

Another option:

```
DECLARE @start int = 0
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS num
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE num BETWEEN @start AND @start+3
```